# Flutter : How to turn of the initial sound of google in speech to text

Tags: flutter, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

Hello flutter developers, I am working on a project where I need to change the initial sound when we call `SpeechToText.listen()`.

Please help me to solve this problem, I searched a lot to solve this problem, please kindly help me developers.

Comment: How are you doing speech to text? Is it a package or built in functionality?

Comment: It is an package of flutter for android and iOS,,, https://pub.dev/packages/speech_to_text this is what i am talking about.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve it by this way:

1. Download the sound and store it in your assets folder
2. Install `audioplayers` in your pubsec.yaml file. ([link](https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayers))
3. Now you can play sound on `onTap` and with that you can also call your `listen()` method.

Here's an example:

```js
 void main() => runApp(MyApp());
    
    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      final player = AudioCache();

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          home: Scaffold(
            body: SafeArea(
              child: TextButton(
                child: Text("play "),
                onPressed: () {
                  player.play('note1.wav');
                  // your other functions 
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for replying,,, And it is a very great answer for other question,, but brother that is not what I asked. Again thank you.